# Heroku migrate app from cedar-10 to cedar-14

Tags: python, django, heroku, heroku-toolbelt

I am just having an issue to push my changes after I followed steps to upgrade my heroku instance from cedar-10 to cedar-14. Although it works if I create new app and apply existing code, it doesn't work to on production app.

> Error

```
-----> Python app detected
ERROR:root:code for hash md5 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 139, in 
globals()[func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 91, in __get_builtin_constructor
raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type md5
ERROR:root:code for hash sha1 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 139, in 
globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 91, in __get_builtin_constructor
raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha1
ERROR:root:code for hash sha224 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 139, in 
globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 91, in __get_builtin_constructor
raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha224
ERROR:root:code for hash sha256 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 139, in 
globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 91, in __get_builtin_constructor
raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha256
ERROR:root:code for hash sha384 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 139, in 
globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 91, in __get_builtin_constructor
raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha384
ERROR:root:code for hash sha512 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 139, in 
globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 91, in __get_builtin_constructor
raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha512
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/app/.heroku/python/bin/pip", line 9, in 
load_entry_point('pip==1.5.6', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.36-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 343, in load_entry_point
return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.36-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2309, in load_entry_point
return ep.load()
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.36-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2015, in load
entry = __import(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['name'])
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/init.py", line 10, in 
from pip.util import get_installed_distributions, get_prog
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/util.py", line 18, in 
from pip.vendor.distlib import version
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/vendor/distlib/version.py", line 14, in 
from .compat import string_types
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/distlib/compat.py", line 31, in 
from urllib2 import (Request, urlopen, URLError, HTTPError,
ImportError: cannot import name HTTPSHandler
ERROR:root:code for hash md5 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 139, in 
globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 91, in __get_builtin_constructor
raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type md5
ERROR:root:code for hash sha1 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 139, in 
globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 91, in __get_builtin_constructor
raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha1
ERROR:root:code for hash sha224 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 139, in 
globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 91, in __get_builtin_constructor
raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha224
ERROR:root:code for hash sha256 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 139, in 
globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 91, in __get_builtin_constructor
raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha256
ERROR:root:code for hash sha384 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 139, in 
globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 91, in __get_builtin_constructor
raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha384
ERROR:root:code for hash sha512 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 139, in 
globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 91, in __get_builtin_constructor
raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha512
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/app/tmp/buildpacks/python/vendor/pip-pop/pip-diff", line 15, in 
from pip.req import parse_requirements
File "/app/tmp/buildpacks/python/vendor/pip-pop/pip/__init.py", line 15, in 
from pip.vcs import git, mercurial, subversion, bazaar # noqa
File "/app/tmp/buildpacks/python/vendor/pip-pop/pip/vcs/mercurial.py", line 10, in 
from pip.download import path_to_url
File "/app/tmp/buildpacks/python/vendor/pip-pop/pip/download.py", line 38, in 
from pip.vendor import requests, six
File "/app/tmp/buildpacks/python/vendor/pip-pop/pip/vendor/requests/__init.py", line 58, in 
from . import utils
File "/app/tmp/buildpacks/python/vendor/pip-pop/pip/vendor/requests/utils.py", line 26, in 
from .compat import parse_http_list as parse_list_header
File "/app/tmp/buildpacks/python/vendor/pip-pop/pip/_vendor/requests/compat.py", line 7, in 
from .packages import chardet
File "/app/tmp/buildpacks/python/vendor/pip-pop/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/__init.py", line 3, in 
from . import urllib3
File "/app/tmp/buildpacks/python/vendor/pip-pop/pip/vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/__init_.py", line 10, in 
from .connectionpool import (
File "/app/tmp/buildpacks/python/vendor/pip-pop/pip/vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 31, in 
from .connection import (
File "/app/tmp/buildpacks/python/vendor/pip-pop/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 45, in 
from .util.ssl import (
File "/app/tmp/buildpacks/python/vendor/pip-pop/pip/vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/__init_.py", line 5, in 
from .ssl_ import (
File "/app/tmp/buildpacks/python/vendor/pip-pop/pip/vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl.py", line 2, in 
from hashlib import md5, sha1, sha256
ImportError: cannot import name md5
$ pip install -r requirements.txt
ERROR:root:code for hash md5 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 139, in 
globals()[func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 91, in __get_builtin_constructor
raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type md5
ERROR:root:code for hash sha1 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 139, in 
globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 91, in __get_builtin_constructor
raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha1
ERROR:root:code for hash sha224 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 139, in 
globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 91, in __get_builtin_constructor
raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha224
ERROR:root:code for hash sha256 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 139, in 
globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 91, in __get_builtin_constructor
raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha256
ERROR:root:code for hash sha384 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 139, in 
globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 91, in __get_builtin_constructor
raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha384
ERROR:root:code for hash sha512 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 139, in 
globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 91, in __get_builtin_constructor
raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha512
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/app/.heroku/python/bin/pip", line 9, in 
load_entry_point('pip==1.5.6', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.36-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 343, in load_entry_point
return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.36-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2309, in load_entry_point
return ep.load()
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.36-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2015, in load
entry = __import(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['name'])
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/init.py", line 10, in 
from pip.util import get_installed_distributions, get_prog
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/util.py", line 18, in 
from pip._vendor.distlib import version
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/distlib/version.py", line 14, in 
from .compat import string_types
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/distlib/compat.py", line 31, in 
from urllib2 import (Request, urlopen, URLError, HTTPError,
ImportError: cannot import name HTTPSHandler
! Push rejected, failed to compile Python app
```

---

Any idea what it can be ?

Answer (score 7):

Heroku support told me:

> This is not exactly a bug, moving between cedar-10 and cedar-14 is an entire operating system upgrade and creating a disk image with completely parity is nearly impossible. You can purge the build cache on your own with the `repo:purge_cache` command via [heroku-repo plugin](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-repo%20heroku-repo%20plugin).

Following those steps worked for me:

```
$ heroku plugins:install heroku-repo
$ heroku repo:purge_cache
```

Comment: This worked for me - any chance of making it the accepted answer?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up opening a ticket directly through support on Heroku platform.

Obviously, it was a bug on their side. So, an Engineer from Heroku needed to **purge build cache** for my application. After that action, I was able to push new changes and deploy new release.